# memory leak in php json_encode()

Tags: php, apache

I have a problem with apache httpd and php. Many child processes of apache httpd took large amounts of memory and my server hung up.

This is a sample code generates the same problem.

```
// some large data from remote server consisting of utf8 unicde char.
// (It's a just example.)
$text = str_repeat("abcdefg123456한글입니다", 100);
$data = "{\"result\":[" . str_repeat("{\"" . $text . "\":\"" . $text . "\"},", 1000);
$data = rtrim($data, ",");
$data .= "]}";

// make a json object
$json = json_decode($data);

// manipulating the json object

// return a result
echo json_encode($json);
```

In my php code, after converted the large json object consists of utf8 strings into a json string for returning a result, memory usage of a httpd process was increased over than 160m and remained.
(The value of memory_limit in php.ini is 32m.)

I investigated the problem through strace. json_encode() called so many mmap() syscalls and didn't call any munmap() syscalls.

I posted a problem to php bug report but I haven't recevied any reply yet.
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69305

I think that json_encode() has memory leak problem. Is there anyone who has the same issue?

I meant please give me some advice on this problem.

Comment: @mattball I attached some detailed information.

Comment: @user3413814 How did you manage to figure out it was json_encode() that was calling mmap? I ran the same code with memory limit disabled and no issue.

Comment: @s.pinkus I didn't change any memory options from default php.ini. I think that mmap() is called by default malloc() behavior.

Comment: printed memory_usage() log; memory_get_usage(): 21136824, memory_get_usage(true): 21495808, memory_get_peak_usage(): 29759712, memory_get_peak_usage(true): 30146560

Comment: Did you find the error? I'm encountering the issue with json_decode. It adds .5MB to memory every time I call it.

Comment: @own3n No. I haven't found any cause of this problem yet.